# How to order documents by distance when using Collection(Edm.GeographyPoint) on the documents

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I have an index with different **products**. Each product is **available in many stores**. One field of the index is a **Collection(Edm.GeographyPoint)** which holds the coordinates of the stores where the product is available.

Some **example data** (CSV) that´s imported in the index:

```
"product","vendor","coordinates"
"Coca Cola 0.5l","Billa","[{ ""type"": ""Point"", ""coordinates"": [48.1184669,16.2030506]},{ ""type"": ""Point"", ""coordinates"": [48.1184977,16.1877297]},{ ""type"": ""Point"", ""coordinates"": [48.1340644,16.2809381]}]"
"Nöm Mix Joghurt 250mg","Billa","[{ ""type"": ""Point"", ""coordinates"": [48.1184669,16.2030506]},{ ""type"": ""Point"", ""coordinates"": [48.1184977,16.1877297]},{ ""type"": ""Point"", ""coordinates"": [48.1340644,16.2809381]}]"
"Red Bull Dose 250ml","Billa","[{ ""type"": ""Point"", ""coordinates"": [48.1184669,16.2030506]},{ ""type"": ""Point"", ""coordinates"": [48.1184977,16.1877297]},{ ""type"": ""Point"", ""coordinates"": [48.1340644,16.2809381]}]"
```

Now I want to sort the results of a query by distance.

**Search query**

```
search=red bull&$count=true&$orderby=geo.distance(coordinates, geography'POINT(48.1078023 16.1692154)') asc
```

That works fine if I have a single geographic point in each dataset but as soon as it´s a collection of points I get the following error:

> "Invalid expression: The argument for an invocation of a function with name 'geo.distance' is not a single value. All arguments for this function must be single values.\r\nParameter name: $orderby"

My question is if there is another geo function which allows me to order the datasets by the points in a collection or if I have to use another pattern for my data structure?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to sort by collection fields in Azure Search, including geo-point fields.

What would be needed to enable this is some way to aggregate over a collection field to produce a single value for each document on which to sort. For example, if you wanted to sort by a collection of numbers, you'd have to choose whether to sort on their average, minimum, maximum, sum, or some other aggregate function. It's less clear what aggregation you'd want for a collection of geospatial co-ordinates.

Since Azure Search does not support this concept of aggregating collections during sorting, it isn't possible to sort documents by collections today. If your goal is to sort stores and not products, where each store has a single geo-location, then I recommend creating a second index for stores.

Comment: Do you have an idea how to solve that problem? I´ve product "X" which is available at n-stores. I would like that the customer get´s the nearest prodcut (and only products whithin a defined distance) as result to his search.

Comment: You'd have to create an index of stores, each of which has a list of products, so you can sort the stores by distance from a given point, since Azure Search does not support sorting on collections today. Feel free to request this capability on User Voice: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search

Comment: That would have the same effect as adding a product n-times with differen location data to the index where n is the amount of stores, right? My problem here is: If a customer searches for "coca cola" he will get a bunch of the "same" coca cola product as a response (ordered by distance). That´s not a nice solution in my opinion. The best would be to only get the nearest "coca cola" product, or the nearest "coca cola" product for each retailer.

Comment: If you directly render the search results, then you will show duplicate products, yes. One workaround for this would be to deduplicate in your app based on product ID, possibly also looking up details for matching products in the products index or another data store.

Comment: I acknowledge this is inconvenient, but Azure Search doesn’t support geo.distance over a collection of points today. Please add an item on User Voice for this to help us prioritize.

Comment: What I don´t understand is this information in the azure **search manual**: "One of the parameters to **geo.distance** must be a geography point constant, and the other must be a field path (or a range variable in the case of a **filter** iterating over a field **of type Collection(Edm.GeographyPoint))**. The order of these parameters doesn't matter.". In my  understanding this means that I can filter by distance also if there are multiple geo points in a collection for one dataset. Seen here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-query-odata-geo-spatial-functions

Comment: Yes, you can filter using a collection of points by using a lambda expression (“any” or “all”). However, there is no support for lambda expressions in $orderby. I will update the documentation to clarify this.

Comment: Thanks Bruce... Can I find an example for that somewhere? E.g. fetch all datasets where at least one of the points in the collection is within a disctance of 5 kilometers.

Comment: Wow, just found it out... "store_loc/any(s: geo.distance(s, geography'POINT(16.1692154 48.1078023)') lt 5)". Works like a charme, thanks Bruce!